# Create three input box and named it as Min,Max and Mul respectively with one Button named it as "Validate". using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Requirement 1: Create three input boxes and named it as Min,Max and Mul respectively.
Requirement 2: Create a button and named it as "Validate".
Requirement 3: Following conditions on the input box should get satisfied.

```
1) Min<Max
2) Mul<Max
3) Mul<=Min 
4) Min and Mul should be the factor of Max.
```

For eg : We have three inputs

```
Min  Max  Mul


5    10   5
```

Requirement 4: If any conditions get false, then that box should be highlighted by making the border of that box as "red".
For eg : We have three inputs:

```
Min  Max  Mul


 5    10   6
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service buddy. We can help you arrive at an answer, not frame the answer as a whole. Kindly show us your efforts and we'll be glad to help. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a (good) question.

Comment: thanks man, i will stuck in this question at 4) condition that is min and mul should be the factor of max. know i solve the problem and get desired output

Comment: how can we convert this code into react js code is given below because i am new to react js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
var min=document.getElementById("demo1").value;
var max=document.getElementById("demo2").value;
var mul=document.getElementById("demo3").value;
min = parseInt(min);
max = parseInt(max);
mul = parseInt(mul);
        
if(!(min < max)){  
document.getElementById('demo1').style.borderColor = "red";
}else{
document.getElementById('demo1').style.borderColor = "";
}
if(!(max > mul)){
document.getElementById('demo2').style.borderColor = "red";
} else{
document.getElementById('demo2').style.borderColor = "";
}
if(!(mul<= min)){
document.getElementById('demo3').style.borderColor = "red";
} else{
document.getElementById('demo3').style.borderColor = "";
}
if(!(max%min==0)){
document.getElementById('demo1').style.borderColor = "red";
} else{
document.getElementById('demo1').style.borderColor = "";
}
if(!(max%mul==0)){
document.getElementById('demo3').style.borderColor = "red";
} else{
document.getElementById('demo3').style.borderColor = "";
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
Min:<input type="text" name="a" id="demo1"><br>
Max:<input type="text" name="b" id="demo2"><br>
Mul:<input type="text" name="c" id="demo3"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Validate</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const min = document.getElementById('min')
const max = document.getElementById('max')
const mul = document.getElementById('mul')

const validate = () => {
  const minValue = Number(min.value)
  const maxValue = Number(max.value)
  const mulValue = Number(mul.value)

  if (minValue < maxValue &&
    maxValue % minValue === 0) min.classList.remove('invalid')
  else min.classList.add('invalid')

  if (mulValue < maxValue &&
    mulValue <= minValue &&
    maxValue % minValue === 0) mul.classList.remove('invalid')
  else mul.classList.add('invaid')
}
```

```css
input.invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label for="min">Min</label>
<input type="number" id="min" name="min">
<br>
<label for="max">Max</label>
<input type="number" id="max" name="max">
<br>
<label for="mul">Mul</label>
<input type="number" id="mul" name="mul">
<br>
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Note: This will not work in IE.